# Internet Explorer 10 only recognizes some links

Tags: hyperlink, internet-explorer-10

I have been testing a site and I found a terrible bug in IE10.

[Tour Monkey - Official site](http://tourmonkey.wdggames.com)

App links are not recognized, but social ones are.
I haven't found anything good already, and the deadline is close. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After giving a look I realized that I had to add some content in the a tag. In this case, an img tag.

Old HTML (working in all but IE):

```
<div class="app-link" id="appstore"><a class="app-link" href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tour-monkey/id810107813?mt=8"></a></div>
```

New HTML

```
<div class="app-link" id="appstore"><a class="app-link" href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tour-monkey/id810107813?mt=8" target="_self"><img src="img/appstore.png"></a></div>
```